# How To add Draggable Event with Containment for Appended Div and Appended Containment

Tags: jquery

How To use jQuery draggable event for append div, I also want to define containment which was also appended ..
I tried may Solutions but none is working ,Please can anybody tell me that how to do this??

my code is like this.

```
<button class="mybutton">push me</button>
<div class="content"></div>

$(".mybutton").click(function(){
    $("<div>drag me</div>").appendTo(".content").draggable();
    $("<div class='containment' style='border: 1px solid blue;display: block; height: 600px; width: 500px;'></div>").appendTo(".content")  
});
```

now I don't want to drag drag me div outside the containment div. is there any way to do so

Comment: You should share your code so far.

Comment: there is a button and when i click on that button a div will be appended                                                               <div class="draggable">draggable</div>                                      and when  i click on this appended div it show a boundary around that div which is also appended                                                             <div class="containment" style="left: 136px; top: 125px; width: 200px; height: 350px; z-index: 5;"></div> now i want to drag that appended div with class draggable inside the div containment div,is there any way to do this?

Comment: Read this before you ask for help- [ask]

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

**DEMO** :http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/E3euD/11/

**HTML**:

```
<button id="mybutton">push me</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){

   $("<div id='containment'><div class='draggable'>drag me</div></div>").
    appendTo("#content");

   $(".draggable").draggable({ containment: "#containment",scroll: false });
});
```

The document is here:
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Hope this helps.